# Trying to stop page from resubmitting form on refresh

Tags: forms, wordpress, header, refresh, contacts

I have the following code. I am trying to prevent my page from resubmitting a form after a page refresh with the header("location:location.php"); However I get a error Listed below

**Error**

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/anderskitson/Sites/fiftyfity/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/contact-form copy.php:7) in /Users/anderskitson/Sites/fiftyfity/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/contact-form copy.php on line 68
```

**Code**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: form-test.php
*/
?>

<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
<?  include_once(ABSPATH. 'wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/contact-form.php'); ?>


<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the wordpress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your wordpress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers 3.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<script>
var i=0;
function test(){

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    document.write( "the number is" + i);
}
}
</script>
<script>
test();
</script>

<?php function make_user_feedback_form() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;


        $ufUserID = $current_user->ID;

        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateFeedback' ) {
            $ufDataUpdate = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_user_feedback', array( 'date' => current_time('mysql'), 'responses' => $_POST["test"]) );
        }
        }?>
    <div id="form">
    <ol>
        <form method="post">
            <li><label for="test">Pick a date Babe:</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="test" value="" /></li> <!-- the (name="test") value is what the ('responses' => $_POST["test"]) value is talking too -->

            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit button" value="Send feedback" /></li>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
            <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback" />
        </form>
    </ol>
    </div>
    <?php 


add_action('the_content','make_user_feedback_form');


header("location: http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/?page_id=90");


?>


<?php 
make_user_feedback_form();
?>




<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938777/headers-already-sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one of the scripts you are including sends headers before WordPress gets a chance to do so, or that the blank lines between your `include_once` and the `get_header` statement makes the web server itself send its default headers.

So, modify the first few lines to look like (i.e. removing the extra PHP opening/closing tags):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: form-test.php
*/

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
include_once(ABSPATH. 'wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/contact-form.php');

/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the wordpress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your wordpress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers 3.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
```

Also check the included files for any data output, `header()` calls or similar adjacent opening/closing  tags.

Comment: Then check the files you are including (and any recursive includes) for output statements, inline HTML data including whitespace or PHP opening/closing tags,  as well as `header()` calls. Any of these will prevent WordPress from sending it's own headers. You can confirm this by temporarily removing the `include_once` statements.

Comment: It is likely that you will have to modify the scripts you are including to send their headers in a WordPress compliant way. In that case, check out the `wp_headers` and `send_headers` filters [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/send_headers?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/class-wp.php)